# Marketing Cloud RetrieveSalesforceObjects - LEAD

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to check if a lead exists in our Sales Cloud instance using AMPscript on a Cloudpage. The code below returns zero records. I'm able to check contact object without any issue. Is there some pre-requisite on the lead object I'm missing?

```
%%[
    var @LeadEmail
    set @LeadEmail = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
       "Lead",
       "Id",
       "Email", "=", "xxxx@xxxx.com" )
]%%

Lead Email = %%=v(@LeadEmail)=%%<br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RetrieveSalesforceObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm) will return a rowset, as there may be multiple results returned. Use [Row](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/row.htm) and [Field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/field.htm) functions to get to your value.

```
%%[
    SET @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'Id', 'Email', '=', 'xxxx@xxxx.com')
    IF RowCount(@rs)>0 THEN
        SET @id = Field(Row(@rs,1),'Id')
    ENDIF
]%%
Lead ID= %%=v(@id)=%%<br>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks for the quick response!